# Are there WWDC 2007 or 2008 videos for iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, wwdc

Does anyone know if at WWDC 2007 or 2008 there were iPhone sessions which were available as video? If so, where could I get these? I know about 2009, but I assume that in 2008 or 2007 very interesting things were covered under the hood regarding deep basics!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You couldn't do native iPhone development in 2007, so the only iPhone-related sessions from then were on doing web development for the device.  There are so many resources for this available out there that I'm not sure you'd gain much from tracking those videos down.

I have the videos from both WWDC 2008 and 2009, and the 2009 sessions have pretty much superseded the 2008 ones.  Even the engineers at Apple were still discovering the best practices for iPhone development in 2008, when the SDK was still in beta.  I can't think of a topic that I didn't think was covered better by the 2009 sessions.

Normally, if you're an Apple Developer Connection Select member you have access to a library of foundational sessions from previous WWDCs on iTunes.  Many Snow Leopard sessions from 2008 are available on there, but no iPhone ones, I think for the reasons I've described about.  They're simply out of date by now.  I'm not aware of any other way of purchasing the 2008 sessions separately.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I thought maybe they left some sessions under the table because they were covered previously in 2008, like some major basics and things like "how all the app store stuff works". But if they're rendundant I might be fine with the 2009 vids.

Comment: It's almost impossible to find these videos in 2020. Do you still have 2008-2008 sessions? Trying to collect all WWDC videos.