# WWDC2008 and 2009 iPhone Videos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I just started watching the 2010-11 WWDC iPhone videos and so far love them, and notice that a lot of them are advancements on videos that were from 2008-9. With that I have two questions:

1) With it being early 2012 now, I was wondering, does anyone think the 2008-2009 WWDC iPhone videos would still be useful?

2) If so, where can I buy them from? Does Apple still sell them? Anyway to get them for free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this is about Apple's developer resources, and not directly a programming question, it's possibly off topic for this site, but I'll answer anyways.

The entire grouping of 2008 and 2009 videos for WWDC are no longer available for purchase, and are not legal to distribute otherwise. They used to have videos from previous WWDCs available on iTunes as "foundational sessions", but I don't know where those have gone. You used to be able to get to them in iTunes by going to the WWDC 2011 videos, then clicking on the "Developer on iTunes - Your Name" tab button at the top of the screen. I remember seeing these as recently as a few months ago, so I don't know when they were pulled. I see WWDC 2009 videos, but I believe those are there because I attended the conference that year, not as a general resource.

As far as the content goes, yes, a lot of material in these presentations builds on something they described in the previous year, but as I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1772150/19679) to a similar question, the newer material tends to supersede the old. There is a lot repeated between years as well, and they do recognize that there are a lot of first-time WWDC attendees now, so I wouldn't say that you're missing a tremendous amount of information by not seeing those older videos.

I say this as someone who attended WWDC all four of the years in question.

As Ilhan suggests, [Stanford's iTunes U course](http://itunes.apple.com/us/course/ipad-iphone-app-development/id495052415) (link is for the new iTunes U app-based course) is a better resource than those older videos for filling in the gaps of the WWDC presentations. Additionally, I can plug [my own iTunes U course](http://itunes.apple.com/us/course/advanced-iphone-development/id497193807) covering the more advanced aspects of iOS development as another free video resource.

Answer (score 1):

A-1) To have a good programming perspective it will be good ta see those videos. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/videos/) you can see all the videos by Apple Developer Team.

A-2) If you have an Apple developer account, you can have them for free.

And a last thing, i suggest you to watch Standford University CS193p Lectures, i-OS application Developement. You can find it from youtube or if you have account you can find plenty of them in i-Tunes..

Comment: Absolutely, that is an amazing sourse

Comment: those are the 2010-11 videos, i was asking about the 2008-9 videos

Comment: @CoDEFRo There are some big changes especially between i-OS 5 and previous ones. Expect from 2011, all of them are almost same, there aren't such big changes in paradigm. Are you a newbie or what is your programming experience in Object-Oriented paradigm these points too are important to give your question an obvious answer.. After all, you go and take a look at Standford Lectures:)

Answer (score 0):

In short - 1. Yes, of course. These videos will long be very useful. 2. All good things come to he who waits :)

Comment: Hmm...like how long does he have to wait? ;)